# 2D Sensor data alignment by correlation

Tags: signal-processing, correlation, image-processing

I have an analog Video Signal in Octave (=Matlab). It is sampled by 14Msample/s. By autocorrelation I have found the line frequency of 15,625KHz. I have 896 samples per Line. But when I transfrom now my array in a Matrix with a row for each line, a line does not start in the beginning of the row, but somewhere in the middle.
I would like to know a statistical approach to align the data correctly in the matrix, without special knowledge about the data. The sensor data has a 2D correlation. I have tried to correlate all columns, for each possible line start but it didn’t work. Did I miss something?
Are there other ways to get a correctly aligned 2D matrix from a 2D sensor, just by statistic?
thx,
Steve